# How watson conversation should say good afternon based on time zone?

Tags: ibm-watson, chatbot, watson

If the user logins to the website in morning, watson would say Good Morning!

If the user logins to the website in afternoon, watson would say Good afternoon!

If the user logins to the website in evening, watson would say Good Evening!

I've written like this

```
{
    "conditions": "now().before('12:00:00')",
    "output": {
    "text": {
    "values": [ "Good morning!" ]
   }
}
```

}

But after closing the json editor the code is changing to like this:

```
{
    "output": {
        "text": {
            "values": [
                "Good morning!"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please say what the solution is? Please provide the entire code for 
["good morning,good afternoon,good evening"]

`

Comment: The JSON that you've written has unclosed `{` characters, so your JSON editor is closing them for you, creating the output JSON that you see in that second fragment. Is that what you intended?

Comment: actually i've written like this in my json editor!!{
    "conditions": "now().before('12:00:00')",
    "output": {
    "text": {
    "values": [ "Good morning!" ]
}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't define conditions in the JSON editor. So it deletes any field that is not part of the schema.

You can set the condition within the tooling UI at the IF statement section. Just paste in your condition part. As the functionality has recently changed, you will need to do the following.

1. On the Welcome node, click the "Customise" Cog. Select "Allow multiple responses".

[image]

2. Set your conditions now at each response part.

[image]

If you are using the workspace API, then I recommend to export your workspace to see how a node block is correctly structured. Alternatively you can check the API spec.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#create_workspace